# How to include OpenGapps in AOSP 12 build?

Tags: android, build, android-source, android-12

I am building AOSP 12 for my Pixel 3a sargo. It worked but I wanted to install Gapps on it. When I tried to flash any Gapps zip in TWRP, it said that my system partition was read-only or full, so I tried remounting it with the read and write permissions. But it showed the same thing. After that, I saw that my system partition was full. So I was wondering, how I can include Gapps while building AOSP? But since OpenGapps is not available for Android 12 (I tried but the build failed), I don't know how to include Gapps in my build.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found how to do this:

First add this to your repo manifest:

```
<remote name="MindTheGapps" fetch="https://gitlab.com/MindTheGapps/" />
<project path="vendor/gapps" name="vendor_gapps" remote="MindTheGapps" revision="sigma" />
```

Then repo sync.
After, add this lines to your device.mk:

```
include vendor/gapps/arm64/arm64-vendor.mk
```

And build.

If you have an error with ELF files, add this line to your boardconfig.mk:

```
BUILD_BROKEN_ELF_PREBUILT_PRODUCT_COPY_FILES := true
```

and this should work.

Comment: What is the difference between tau and sigma revision?

Comment: @antonyjr I guess the tau refers to Android 13 and the sigma refers to Android 12.

Comment: Yes, sigma is Android 12 and tau is Android 13 but there is no documentation on this.